# Rails caching: replacement for expires_in on Rails.cache.fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way to clear up this warning while keeping the brevity of the "get or set" caching call? I really like not having to do a get, then check for nil, then set...

```
# DEPRECATION WARNING: Setting :expires_in on read has been deprecated in favor of setting it on write.

@foo = Rails.cache.fetch("some_key", :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
    some stuff
end
```

Comment: Just want to note that with Rails 4, there's more of a trend towards Russian-doll caching in which there's no expiry time necessary. expiry time can still be easier, but this is sometimes an anti-pattern now.

Comment: Rails 4 doesn't give a deprecation warning for that syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I really like not having to do a get, then check for nil, then set...

Yes, you'll want to avoid doing that on every call, but you'll still have to do that at least once.  Something simple like this may work for you:

```
def smart_fetch(name, options, &blk)
  in_cache = Rails.cache.fetch(name)
  return in_cache if in_cache
  val = yield
  Rails.cache.write(name, val, options)
  return val
end
```

Then in your views you can do:

```
@foo = smart_fetch("some_key") do
  some stuff
end
```

Note that the Rails cache store has a default expiry time you can set when you create it, so you may not need to override that on each call unless you need different expiry times.

Answer (score 5):

Small alterations to the helpful method provided by @briandoll:

```
def smart_fetch(name, options = {}, &blk)
  in_cache = Rails.cache.fetch(name)
  return in_cache if in_cache
  if block_given? 
    val = yield 
    Rails.cache.write(name, val, options) 
    return val 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ConditionalGet/fresh_when
and 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ConditionalGet/expires_in
seem to be your only option from what I can find.

Comment: btw rails 3.1 changes it up a bit by adding rack::cache to the default stack: 
https://gist.github.com/958283

Comment: fresh_when and expires_when are controller methods related to HTTP response; the question is about generic data caching without regard for web services.