# Rails low level query caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

I would like to cache a controller query result because it's a very static data which wont change very often.

So I am wondering if I can just define this method:

```
  def cached_collections
    Rails.cache.fetch('collections', :expires_in => 24.hours) do
      Collection.all
    end
  end
```

And in some way instead using

```
@collections = Collection.all
```

can I just call the method?

```
@collections = cached_collections
```

This is working but it's the right way to do it? before using Memcached or Redis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your method `cached_collections` you are trying to cache a complex object structure (an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`). This is probably achievable, but a much easier approach is to just cache your views or view fragments:

```
<% cache do %>
  <% @collection.each do |item| %>
    <%# do something with item %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can still initialize your queries inside of your controller, e.g.:

```
@collection = Collection.limit(10)
```

Instances of `ActiveRecord::Relation` are lazy; they mimic the behavior of an array in a way, that they won't hit the database until you explicitly access the fetched result, e.g: `@collection.first` or `@collection.each{ #... }`

So no database query as long as your fragments are cached.

Refer to this for caching examples: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Edit:

For JSON requests, you could do it like this:

```
@collection = Collection.all
render :json => Rails.cache.fetch('collections', :expires_in => 24.hours) do
  @collection.to_json
end
```

Again, no request to the database unless your cache is stale and no complex object structure in your cache.

Comment: mm in my case I am not using a view just sending a JSON response json: would it be still possible to cache it in the response?

Comment: I have noticed when the query is stale is not being updated, is that intended?

Comment: It seems like the `expires_in` option has been deprecated, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157059/rails-caching-replacement-for-expires-in-on-rails-cache-fetch

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a look